# MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed when trying to connect to database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, wpf, database-connection

I have a WPF application that I occasionally execute (every few days). It connects to MySQL database and dumps some information in there. Here's the code I use to connect:

```
// connection to the database server
public MySqlConnection con;

public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //initialize connection variables
    con = new MySqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = @"Server = xxx; Database = xxx; Uid = xxx ; Pwd = 'xxx'; charset=utf8;";

}

public bool OpenConnection()
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        //logging any error messages here to custom log files
        return false;
    }
}
```

The application worked just fine for several months. I haven't touched it, apart from running it every now and then, it would successfully connect to the server, do it's job and then exit, closing the connection in the process.

The other day I tried to run it again and I got the following error message:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
```

I can successfully connect to the database using the same parameters from the connection string using phpMyAdmin and I also have a small online web PHP application that reads data from that exact same database and it also successfully connects and runs queries against it. However, that's not the case for the WPF application any more so any suggestions what could be the problem and what went wrong?

P.S. The PHP application is used even more rarely so I don't think it's a high demand issue as no one is actually accessing this database except for the WPF application. Besides, I've tried running it 3 days in a row (different times during the day) and I got the same error every single time.

Comment: did you find the cause of the problem? I am facing the same